# How to extend L.Control.Layers to add custrom filters and is it a good way to do it?

Tags: javascript, user-controls, leaflet

I have markers on a map which represent workers/group of workers and tasks/group of tasks.
Each workers has a list of skills and each tasks require one skill.

I'd like to be able to toggle the display of all the workers or tasks (easily done with `L.featureGroup()` and `L.control.layers()`) but I would also like to filter the current display on skills.

What I mean by "current display" is that if I've decided to hide workers and only display tasks, when I toggle the display for one skill, I don't want the workers having that skill to show up.

Which means that I can't use regular `featureGroup` and regular `controlLayer` to do so since it has no way to perform filtering/applying conditions on show/hide. It either show every markers in the group or hide them all.

I'm tempted to fork the [Control.Layers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Layers.js) and add some callback based logic to it, but I wonder if there is better way of doing it ?

**Edit:**

```
// Backbone stuff
var WorkerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var TaskModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var WorkersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: WorkerModel
});
var TasksCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TaskModel
});

var workersData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    marker: L.marker(new L.LatLng(45,3)),
    coordinates: {
        lat: 45,
        lng: 3
    },
    skills: {
        skillA: {
            name: 'Foo',
            level: 1
        },
        skillB: {
            name: 'Bar',
            level: 7
        },
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'John',
    marker: L.marker(new L.LatLng(48,2)),
    coordinates: {
        lat: 48,
        lng: 2
    },
    skills: {
        skillA: {
            name: 'Foo',
            level: 4
        }, 
        skillD : {
        name: 'Zop',
        level: 3
        }
    }
}];

var tasksData = [{
    id: 1,
    requiredSkill: 'skillA',
    requiredLevel: 5,
    duration: '5',
    marker: L.marker(new L.LatLng(50,2)),
    coordinates: {
        lat: 50,
        lng: 2
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    requiredSkill: 'skillB',
    requiredLeve: 2,
    duration: '1',
    marker: L.marker(new L.LatLng(47,3)),
    coordinates: {
        lat: 47,
        lng: 3
    }
}];

var workers = new WorkersCollection(workersData);
var tasks = new TasksCollection(tasksData);

// We get all the markers that relates to a workers or a tasks with the skillA
var workersMarkerWithSkillA = workers.chain().filter(worker) { 
    return worker.get('skills').has('skillA'); 
}).map(function(worker) { 
    return worker.get('marker');
}).value();

var tasksMarkerWithSkillA = tasks.chain().filter(worker) { 
    return worker.get('skills').has('skillA'); 
}).map(function(worker) {
    return worker.get('marker');
}).value();

var markersWithSkillA = _.concat(workersMarkerWithSkillA, tasksMarkerWithSkillA);


// Same thing with skillB
var workersMarkerWithSkillB = workers.chain().filter(worker) { 
    return worker.get('skills').has('skillB'); 
}).map(function(worker) { 
    return worker.get('marker');
}).value();

var tasksMarkerWithSkillB = tasks.chain().filter(worker) { 
    return worker.get('skills').has('skillB'); 
}).map(function(worker) {
    return worker.get('marker');
}).value();

var markersWithSkillB = _.concat(workersMarkerWithSkillB, tasksMarkerWithSkillB);


// Make the map
var map = L.map('map');
var tileLayer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' });
map.addLayer(tileLayer);

// Make the layers
var workersLayer = new L.featureGroup(workers.pluck('marker'));
var tasksLayer = new L.featureGroup(taskLayer.pluck('marker'));
var skillALayer = new L.featureGroup(markersWithSkillA);
var skillBLayer = new L.featureGroup(markersWithSkillB);

// Then we add everything on the map
var controlLayer = L.control.layers(null, [workersLayer, tasksLayer, markersWithSkillA, markersWithSkillB]);
controlLayer.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Could you share some code for this?

Comment: I'll try to share some relatively similar 'end code' to show what I'm trying to achieve. I can't share the actual code as it's part of a large Backbone App, which make it difficult to extract a working example.

Comment: I've added a code example I've made up but that basically look like what I have. Imagine that I have skill layers for a number of skill (not only the A). You can see that markers are part of multiple layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking the `Control.Layers` as planned, but did very little change to it. I simply added a placeholder section in the HTML it generates.

Then, I build a `FilterModule` in my Backbone Marionette App. The region for that module would be the placeholder I previously defined, and the filtering mechanism is done by a function in the module, which is great since it really depends on the data I show, and not really on the map used to display it.

It's not entirely satisfying since it means hard coupling the App to a forked version of some Leaflet parts, but the change in the fork being minimal it's not that big of a deal, plus, on the Backbone side, it really is only a `DOM#id` to change and the view will show up somewhere else.

You may wonder why I did not simply add a new element in the view instead of filling the original `Control.Layers`'s HTML which would have prevented the coupling I described. It's simply because I may have from 0 to 20 filters based on the data shown and the positioning issue it creates was not worth it. The goal was also to have these filters near the native Layer toggle.